# "askfirst" getty with systemd ("press enter to activate this console")

Tags: debian, terminal, systemd, getty

On a Debian Jessie system with `systemd`, how can I configure the terminals so that a message like `Press enter to activate this console` is displayed and the login prompt does not appear before hitting enter?

With `inittab` this could be done by configuring `askfirst`, but how to do it with `systemd`?

*If possible* I'd prefer to adjust appropriate config files rather than messing with existing `systemd` unit files directly - just like there is `logind.conf` but unfortunately that config file won't help in this case AFAIK.

Comment: If I remember correctly it has something to do with copying the correct service file from ´/lib/systemd/system/´ into a .target.wants file at´/etc/systemd/system/´ and editing it. But I can't tell you very much about it, I was just following some tutorial, maybe I can find it again…

Comment: Sure, that tutorial would be interesting to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With `/etc/inittab` this could be done by configuring `askfirst` …

Actually, it could not.  That's a BusyBox `init` mechanism that doesn't exist in the Linux System 5 `init` clone, one of several ways in which their `/etc/inittab` configuration files are not the same things.

The way to do similar things on a systemd Linux operating system depends from what one is actually doing.  One doesn't necessarily employ it solely for interactive terminal log-on, although you clearly are here.

One common use of `askfirst` is simply for *not having the `getty`+`login` system running for unused virtual terminals*.  systemd doesn't need a non-default setting for this.  With systemd, the `logind` service as packaged already arranges to only start `autovt@N.service` services on demand, when virtual terminals are switched to the foreground.  Terminal login isn't run on virtual terminals that haven't been switched to (and that are not the first or the "reserved" virtual terminals).

The slightly different semantics, of not starting the `getty`+`login` system until one has switched to the virtual terminal *and pressed enter*, are slightly harder to achieve, as they involve either switching on a `getty` option or interposing a program that prints out a message and waits for a line of input before chaining to `getty`.

Only a few `getty` programs have such options, such as Peter Orbaek's `agetty` which has `--wait-cr`.  Most (like Felix von Leitner's `fgetty` and Florian La Roche's `mingetty`) have not.  The remainder (such as Gert Doering's `mgetty`) are ones that expect modems and all of their accompaniments — which of course virtual terminals do not have and which make adapting them to virtual terminal use somewhat tricky.

The chain-loading equivalent to `--wait-cr` on a virtual terminal, a simple program that prints a message, then reads a line from the terminal (in canonical mode), and then chain loads, is a fairly simple program.

Employing such options, employing different `getty` programs, or interposing utility chain-loading programs "before" `getty`, all involve either writing one or more unit file override files under `/etc/systemd/system` with `systemctl edit` (changing the `ExecStart` setting) or simply pointing `autovt@.service` at a local unit file of one's own devising instead of at `getty@.service`.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [`login-prompt`](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh/guide/login-prompt.html).  *nosh Guide*.  JdeBP's Softwares.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233855/5132
- Werner Fink and Karel Zak. [`agetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/agetty.8.html).  Unbuntu 15.04 manual pages.