# How can I get systemd to use qingy as my default tty program instead of agetty (debian jessie)?

Tags: debian, systemd, tty

I'd like to use a different tty program than agetty on my debian jessie machine (specifically, qingy). 
The tty creation is controlled by systemd via the (auto-created as I understand) /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service

What is the "systemd way" for modifying/controlling/replacing agetty as my default tty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systemd way is to create a *service template* that starts your alternative TTY login service …

```
[Unit]
Description=Qingy on %I
Documentation=info:qingy
BindTo=dev-%i.device
After=dev-%i.device systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service

[Service]
Environment=TERM=linux
ExecStart=/sbin/qingy %I --no-shutdown-screen
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillSignal=SIGHUP

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
```

… and then to make sure that the `autovt@.service` template is an alias for this instead of for `getty@.service`, as it is out of the box.

```
ln -s qingy@.service /etc/systemd/system/autovt@.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

(Note that this is **not** modifying the pre-packaged `/lib/systemd/system/autovt@.service` that comes in the box.  This is using systemd's conventional `/etc`/`/lib` dichotomy to **override** it with a local, administrator-defined, one.)

Stop an existing `autovt@ttyN.service` and let `logind` auto-start it again, to see this take effect.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132

Comment: **autovt@.service** can be found under _/lib/systemd/system/_, the debian qingy package installs to _/usr/sbin/qingy_ (**not** _/sbin/qingy_) plus it seems to be broken anyway - I couldn't get the syntax for the binary to run properly. I've ended up attacking the problem from a different (simpler) perspective which was a lightweight dm. I've abandoned a dm at all, use the text/getty login, and a line in my _.bashrc_ checks if I'm in tty1 and if so runs _startx_. I'm not sure of correct etiquette in marking this resolved or not, because I can't confirm... (sorry stackexchange newbie here)