# Ctrl+Alt+F6 to access a linux container?

Tags: tty, lxc, x-server

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-F6</kbd> lead to a virtual console.

A `lxc` container is running on my computer.  How to configure the host so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> goes to the virtual console of the container?

Moreover, how to configure the host so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> goes to an x server running inside the container?

Comment: The first will probably involve writing a systemd service file, that runs `lxc console ...`. Read here for more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/127903 . Note the part about "NAutoVTs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out, mainly inspired by [this post on arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=103319).

- Disable the `getty` currently running behind `tty6` by removing `/etc/init/tty6.conf`, this would take effect after rebooting.
- Allow the container to access `tty6` by adding `lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 4:6 rwm` to the container's configuration
- Autostart `getty` in the container, by editing `/etc/init/tty6.conf` instead the container

  ```
  start on runlevel [23] # and not-container <- not-container is commented out

  stop on runlevel [!23]

  respawn
  exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
  ```

Now  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> is container's console.

Additional operations are need for `tty[1-4]`, as `/dev/tty[1-4]` in the container are not tty devices.

Comment: This answer only applies to Linux-based operating systems that are using Upstart.